# CMake error: install TARGETS given target "Foo::Foo" which is an alias

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add `install()` support for [Mach7](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7/). Here is part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(Mach7 INTERFACE)
add_library(Mach7::Mach7 ALIAS Mach7)

install(TARGETS Mach7::Mach7
    EXPORT Mach7Targets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Runtime
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Development
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT Runtime
    ......
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the alias `Mach7::Mach7` for `install(TARGETS ...` and get err or below:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (install):
  install TARGETS given target "Mach7::Mach7" which is an alias.
```

Why cannot I use ailas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#id5

> The  may not be used to modify properties of , that is, it may not be used as the operand of `set_property()`, `set_target_properties()`, `target_link_libraries()` etc. **An *ALIAS* target may not be installed or exported.**